# How exactly is the distance between 2 parallel lines in 3D the cross product of the unit vector of the lines with a vector joining them both?

Tags: vectors, 3d

According to my textbook, the formula for the distance between 2 parallel lines has been given as below:

[image]

Where PT is a vector from the first line that makes a perpendicular on the second line, vector B is a vector to which both the lines are parallel to and vector (a2 - a1) is a vector that joins one arbitrary point on the second line, to yet another arbitrary point on the other

This is what I am confused by. The book, along with the numerous threads I've scoured through already provide similar diagrams for the proof:

[image]

From what I understand, the crossing of ST with B should yield us a vector pointing OUT of the plane to  which the lines (and in conjunction, ST) belong

How would that yield us TP/PT? TP/PT belongs to the same plane to which the lines and ST belong as well, so how'd crossing ST and  B yield us PT?

I understand the end goal is to calculate the MAGNITUDE of the shortest vector joining both the lines, but I can't seem to understand how d is the magnitude of PT as opposed to being the magnitude of the vector jutting OUT of the plane

Comment: The magnitude of the cross product is the product of the magnitudes times the sine of the angle between the vectors. Look at your picture and see that segment TP has length equal to .... what?

Comment: I don't blame you for finding this formula unbelievable. It almost seems like an accident that it works. And it's only good in three dimensions, unlike more general methods for finding the distance between parallel lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula uses only the *magnitude* of the the cross product. And the magnitude of $u \times v$ is $\|u\|$ times $\|v\|$ times the sine of the angle between $u$ and $v$. So, using the cross product is just a fancy way of getting the sine of an angle. And, if you do a bit of trig, you'll see that the sine of an angle is exactly what you need to calculate the desired distance. The direction of the cross product is irrelevant in all of this, so you don't need to worry about the fact that it's perpendicular to the plane in which all the action occurs.

Comment: This was what I had trouble coming to 'terms' with. I'd initially assumed the cross product's resultant vector's direction had SOMETHING to do with the final answer, and wracked my head trying to understand it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The length of the cross product of two vectors is $|a \times b| = |a| |b| \sin(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between them.

Comment: Beat me by 36  seconds  :-)